# Wordpress: function to replace content for custom post status

Tags: wordpress

I created custom post status "blocked" via register_post_status (like this [register_post_status not showing post_status in status dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557810/register-post-status-not-showing-post-status-in-status-dropdown)).

Now I want to replace content on posts with this status via functions.php.

I tried something like this

```
function block_by_status ($post_object) {
     global $wp_query;
     if( 'blocked' == $wp_query->post->post_status ) {
         return 'This post is blocked';
     }
}

add_action('the_post','block_by_status');
```

But it doesn't work, please somebody help?

Comment: Have you tried: `add_filter('the_content', 'block_by_status');`

Comment: I tried this, partially works, but the page displays the heading h1, a row with meta-data (date, category) and comments. Can all this be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the content you can do something as simple as:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'block_by_status');
```

and to hide the title you can use:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'block_by_status', 10, 2 );
```

If you want to go further than that, I suggest editing the template in the theme folder.

For pages you need to edit `page.php` and for posts you need to edit `posts.php` or `singular.php`, depends on the theme you are using.

So you can do something like this:

In the `functions.php` file:

```
function block_by_status ($post_object) {
     global $wp_query;
     if( 'blocked' == $wp_query->post->post_status ) {
         return true;
     }
}
```

and then in the files I referenced above (Depends on your theme):

```
<?php if (!block_by_status()) { ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
        <?php the_content() ?>
        <?php get_sidebar() ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php } else {
    echo 'This post is blocked';
} ?>
```

So you use your function as a boolean and just hide what you dont want users to see.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that the problem can be solved without editing the theme files, but if not, I’ll do it your way

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how your theme files are laid out, there are other filters that you can use to hide things, but i dont know how much you are showing or what you want to hide and what you dont want to hide. If you update your question I can update the answer with better info for you.

Comment: it's okay, I made changes to the few theme files, it works now, thanks!

Comment: No problem, please accept my answer if you are happy with it.