# register_post_status not registering new post status

Tags: wordpress

So Im trying to add a custom post status to my posts but when i add the below code, the post status does not appear in the All section of the posts.

I tried disabling all plugins and changing the theme but the issue still persists.

```
// Registering custom post status
function wpb_custom_post_status(){
  
   register_post_status('rejected', array(
    'label'                     => _x( 'Rejected', 'post' ),
    'public'                    => true,
    'exclude_from_search'       => false,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Rejected <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Rejected <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
   ));
 
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_post_status' );
```

Any help would be appriciated. I should mention that my Wordpress installation is up to date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557810/register-post-status-not-showing-post-status-in-status-dropdown/49569592

Answer (score 1):

You registered the status but you aren't displaying it.

```
// Registering custom post status
function wpb_custom_post_status(){
    register_post_status('tbd', array(
        'label'                      => _x( 'TBD', 'post' ),
        'public'                     => false,
        'exclude_from_search'        => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'     => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list'  => true,
        'label_count'                => _n_noop( 'TBD <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'TBD <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_post_status' );

// Using jQuery to add it to post status dropdown
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php', 'wpb_append_post_status_list');
function wpb_append_post_status_list(){
global $post;
$complete = '';
$label = '';
if($post->post_type == 'post'){
if($post->post_status == 'tbd'){
$complete = 'selected="selected"';
$label = '<span id="post-status-display">TBD</span>';
}
    
        echo "<script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery( 'select[name=\"_status\"]' ).append( '<option value=\"tbd\">TBD</option>' );
    });
    </script>";
}
}
```