# Add "disable" status to WP posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I've used this code a while back (a couple of years(?) ago) and it worked just fine. Client wanted to have a few projects/services hidden for a while, the specialist for that field retired.

```
function project_disabled_status(){
    register_post_status('disabled', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Disabled', 'project' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Disabled <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Disabled <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
    ) );    
}
add_action( 'init', 'project_disabled_status' );
```

However, I've added it now to another website with similar request, but it doesn't seem to work anymore, it doesn't add the "Disabled" status in the visibility area. I've tried on a couple of other websites, no luck. No idea what changed.

Anyone have another solution for this? The goal is to have a few custom post types disabled and not visible in archive pages, only by using direct link.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [register\_post\_status not registering new post status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649973/register-post-status-not-registering-new-post-status)

Answer (score 0):

Custom post statuses are still work-in-progress.

Registering a post status WILL NOT make it automatically appear in your sites admin panel. You will have to handle displaying the custom post status on the front-end yourself.

See this question for more information: [Custom post status not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298346/custom-post-status-not-appearing)